# How to interpret MetricKit histogrammedApplicationResumeTime values?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, mobile, metrickit

I've implemented collecting MetricKit data for my app. And I don't understand meaning of `histogrammedApplicationResumeTime` values from `appLaunch` metric. I explored data and found, that there are can be really huge values – around hours.

For example, let's see one data snapshot from real user:
[image: appResumeTime data snapshot]

It seems unbelievable, that `resumeTime` takes **10902720ms** (1 hour).

We've also built a bar chart per percentiles and it looks crazy:
[image]
**p85** – 1030ms | **p95** – 1.52 million ms | **p99** – 13.2 million ms (3.5 hours)

Documentation says:

> A histogram of the different amounts of time taken to resume the app from the background.

For me it sounds like: *time between moment, when user launch app, which is in background mode already, to the moment, when app comes to foreground stay.*

But the real data shows that it isn't.

Can somebody describe what really means `histogrammedApplicationResumeTime` metric? Have somebody ideas, why such large values are presented in collected data?